# Static elements caught in fixed header

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm pretty new to html and css and I want to make a fixed header. But whenever I try, static  elements get caught behind it unless I give them position: absolute. Here is my CSS:

```
.heady {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: hsla(176, 100%, 75%, 0.24);
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.header {
    margin: auto;   
    width:25%;
    text-align: center;

}
.header h1{
    font-family: Arial;
    color: gray;
    border-right: 3px solid powderblue;
    border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
}


html body {
    background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5b/3f/9a/5b3f9a68aaa539d6997bbc0c74efa45b--pretty-star-blue-aesthetic.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.support {
    position: static;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <body><div class="heady">
<div class="header"><h1>Big Title</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="support"><p>This is some text stuck behind the header</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's unclear how you want your page to look like. Do you want the header to be on the top, and other content to begin below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using margin instead of a position for the header.

- Select the position of the header using top
- Then, add a margin top for the first element that will appear below the header.

```css
.heady {
    position: fixed;
    top:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: hsla(176, 100%, 75%, 0.24);
}
.header {
    margin: auto;   
    width:25%;
    text-align: center;

}
.header h1{
    font-family: Arial;
    color: gray;
    border-right: 3px solid powderblue;
    border-left: 3px solid powderblue;
}


html body {
    background: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5b/3f/9a/5b3f9a68aaa539d6997bbc0c74efa45b--pretty-star-blue-aesthetic.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
.support {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="heady">
        <div class="header"><h1>Big Title</h1></div>
    </div>
   <div class="support">This is some text stuck behind the header</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.